# How to get Stings from Fragment to Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have an app that works with Stings but I doesn*t know how to send String from a Fragment to an Activity. Somebody help me but I dont understand the code well.So If somebody have questions he could ask me and I could anserd it

Please help me

Fragment:

```
public class Fragment_1 extends Fragment {



    String text;
    int zähler = 0;
    String teile[];
    String in = "", in2 = "", in3 = "";
    ListView listView;
    public String [] liste;
    String value = "MIT";



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("Key",value);

        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        intent.putExtras(bundle);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
       // final Button but = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.but1) ;





        new doit().execute();



        return view;
    }
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String mesg = "MIT";





    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);


        Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (data != null) {

            String receivedString = data.getString("Key");

            Log.d("MainActivity", receivedString);
        }





        Log.d("MainActivity", "Bitte nicht" );



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an interface in your fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
{

private MyInterface mListener;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(bundle);
    mListener.passString("Hello from fragment!");
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context)
{
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof MyFragment.MyInterface)
    {
        mListener = (MyInterface) context;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString());
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach()
{
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface MyInterface
{
    void passString(String string);
}

}
```

And in your activity you have to implement the method of the interface:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyFragment.MyInterface
{
String myString;
//other methods like onCreate and so on...

@Override
public void passString(String string)
{
    myString = string;
}

}
```

myString will be the string which you passed from the fragment to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are, simply use a bundle to transfer data from your fragment back to your activity:

```
//sending data from your fragment
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("KEY",value);

Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
intent.putExtras(bundle);


//Receving data inside your Activity
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
if (data != null)
        {
            String receivedString= data.getString("KEY");

        }
```

Comment: data is always null for me

Comment: how are you going back from fragment to activity??

Comment: As you wrote. The first part in the fragment and the second in the activity

Comment: No no what I am asking is when you're in your fragment how do you traverse back to your activity where you are accessing your data.

Comment: oh sorry, I solved it. It works. However, change `intent.putExtra(bundle);` to `intent.putExtras(bundle);` because putExtras method is for bundles, putExtra for strings and so on.

Comment: I directly wrote the code here so might have missed the 's', anyway I have edited the code. If you liked it and it solved your problem please upvote and enjoy!!!

Comment: However, I think that using a bundle in this case isn't a good solution because you can't know when your data is passed. For example, if you want to show a toast after the data passing, you have to create an infinite loop in a thread to verify if the data is passed or not and it's ugly.

Comment: It won't be you can send the bundle when you traverse from your fragment back to your activity. why do you have to set the loop???

Comment: Because if you want to get data from fragment in onCreate for example, you'll never get data. You have to call a method, which is in your activity and gets the data when it is prepared.

Comment: For example before I had to put the get method in onResume because I could not know when data was passed. Yes, I know when it was passed, of course, but the code doesn't notice if it was passed. So, at the moment 1 I send the data. I can't see our toast. At the moment 2 I exit and open the app and then I can see the toast because there there is the get method. I hope I have explained myself.

Comment: What are you saying tell me a flow where the condition you mentioned above is required. When you come back from your fragment to activity you can receive the bundle in onCreate also.

Comment: What do you mean for "come back"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145996/discussion-between-curio-and-sumit).